# What does an iphone user need to use a Monotouch app?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

If a user wants to use a Monotouch app, what does he need to download onto his iPhone prior to using the app? Also how heavy is the stuff he needs to download?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for a mistake. The title is "What does an iphone user need to [USE] Monotouch app?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monotouch is completely transparent to the end user - the user just buys a monotouch app from the app store, and it just works, in exactly the same way a normal iphone application works.

The size of the app will very depending on how many of the frameworks are used by the app.

Comment: Is there a way to know what the size of the app would be on a user's iphone?

Comment: You're basically asking "how long is a piece of string?". Either try and find an app that's similar to what you want to write and see how big that is, or try one of the samples ( http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Samples ) that's close to what you want to do and see how large that compiles to be.

Comment: Well I can to that as well :). However I thought that someone with experience developing MT apps could tell me if the size differs (a lot).

Answer (score 1):

The user shouldn't need anything. The MonoTouch SDK

> is delivered as a static compiler that
>   turns .NET executables and libraries
>   into native applications. There is no
>   JIT or interpreter shipped with your
>   application, only native code.

From: http://monotouch.net/FAQ

Comment: But the size of MT app is A LOT bigger than of Objective-C app. So it'd not just native code, right?!

Comment: Where do you see that the size of an MT app is "A LOT" bigger than an Obj-C app? No, it's only native code. Now, if MT base/wrapper classes have to be compiled into the app, then yes, that's more code, so more binary data, but everything is turned into a native iOS binary.

Comment: I haven't seen it anywhere, but I read blogs and developers complaining that their MT app is a lot bigger than of the OC one. They mention that 1MB OC app is approx 5MB MT.

Comment: Yes, MT apps are in general a little bigger than ObjC ones. For example, my app Quicklytics, when compressed, has a size of aprox 3Mb, which is not much more than the minimum app size you can do with MonoTouch. Can you make smaller apps with ObjC? Yes. A similar app will likely be smaller, but it'll also take more time to do. MT includes lots of things, like garbabe collection, for free. In ObjC, you would have to take care of that. It's a tradeoff. Personally, as long as the size is below 20Mb and the app is fast, I dont care.

Comment: Eduardo, have you made an app which size reached 20MB? we plan to build an app with substantial amount of graphics and MT's DLLs and that's the reason why we care about the size.